# $\epsilon_0$ is closed under addition, multiplication, exponentiation of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Question: Let $f: \Bbb{N}\rightarrow \text{Ord}$ (where "Ord" is the set of ordinals) be defined inductively by:
$$f(0)=\omega\\  f(n^+)=\omega^{f(n)}$$
Let $\epsilon_0=\{\sup f(i) : i \in \Bbb{N}\}.$ If $\alpha,\beta<\epsilon_0$ then show that:

1. $\alpha + \beta < \epsilon_0$
2. $\alpha\beta <\epsilon_0$
3. $\alpha^\beta < \epsilon_0$

---

Attempt at solution: The result seems clear if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are finite. So, assume $\beta$ is a nonzero limit ordinal. Then by definition:

$\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\xi : \xi<\beta\} < \alpha + \epsilon_0 = \sup\{\alpha+\xi : \xi <\epsilon_0\}=\epsilon_0$

$\alpha\beta = \sup\{\alpha\xi : \xi <\beta\} < \alpha \epsilon_0 < \epsilon_0 \bullet \epsilon_0 = \epsilon_0$

$\alpha^\beta = \sup\{\alpha^\xi : \xi < \beta\}<\alpha^{\epsilon_0} = \epsilon_0$ because $\sup(\alpha,\alpha^2,...)=\epsilon_0$

Am I on the right track?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you have to justify why $\sup(\alpha+\xi:\xi<\epsilon_0)=\epsilon_0$ and $\sup(\alpha,\alpha^2,...)=\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Also $\epsilon_0\cdot\epsilon_0<\epsilon_0$ isn't true.

Comment: @zyx He proved its existence, in a small fragment of ZF.

Comment: For a set of ordinals, sup is the same thing as union.

Comment: @Wojowu I was kind of meaning that because $\omega^{\epsilon_0} = \epsilon_0$, then $\alpha\beta < \omega^{\epsilon_0} \omega^{\epsilon_0} < \omega^{2\epsilon_0} = \omega^{\epsilon_0}=\epsilon_0$ I thought that $2\epsilon_0 = \epsilon_0$. Is this not correct?